# Turn a string into a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, api, dictionary

I have a simple string that I got from an API:

```
IP Address: 8.8.8.8

Country: <country>

State: <state>

City: <city:

Latitude: <Latitude>

Longitude: <Longitude>
```

But i'm trying to turn this string in a dictionary like:

```
{
'IP Address': '8.8.8.8',
'Country': '<country>',
'State': '<state>',
'City': '<city>',
'Latitude': '<Latitude>',
'Longitude': '<Longitude>',
}
```

Comment: have you tried `json.loads`?

Comment: @Tranbi yeah, I tried, but it seems like it only works when the string is already in dictionary format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
out = {}
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if not line:
            continue
        k, v = line.split(":", maxsplit=1)
        out[k.strip()] = v.strip()

print(out)
```

this creates and prints the dictionary:

```py
{
    "IP Address": "8.8.8.8",
    "Country": "<country>",
    "State": "<state>",
    "City": "<city>",
    "Latitude": "<Latitude>",
    "Longitude": "<Longitude>",
}
```

Comment: I wish I'd have that level of knowledge, thank you very much, I didn't find an answer that worked as well as yours.

Comment: But I just don't get the "if not line" statement, why put a check if the loop is not going through a line? There are no blanks... If you could explain this part to me I would be grateful.

Comment: @AndréChrisostomo `if not line:` is the equivalent of `if line == "":` (means I want to skip empty lines with no data)